# What is the condition that determines a proper integral?

Tags: calculus

I am reading **Problems in Calculus of One Variable** by I.A.Maron and the author seems to make the following statements: 
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin t}{\sqrt t}\text{dt}\text{ is proper integral since }\lim_{t\to+0}\frac{\sin t}{\sqrt t}=0$$ 
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin t}{t}\text{dt}\text{ is proper integral since }\lim_{t\to+0}\frac{\sin t}{t}=1$$

Does this mean that $\int^{a}_{b}f(x)\text{dx}$ is a proper integral iff $\lim_{t\to+b}f(x)$ is a finite value and $b\neq\infty$?

Comment: Well, this could be called "a proper, usual Riemann integral in disguise of improper integral". Observe that as in both cases the functions are not *actually* defined at zero they could formally be named as improper. Yet, what is way more important than merely be defined at a point is to be defined on some (left, right) neighborhood of the point and be **bounded** there. I guess it may all depend on definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two kinds of improper integrals on the real line:

- Those where the domain of integration is unbounded, on one or both sides (e.g. $\int_1^\infty x^{-2}\ dx=1$)
- Those where the integrand itself is unbounded at one or more points (e.g. $\int_{-1}^1x^{-2/3}\ dx=6$; unbounded at 0)

There are some improper integrals satisfying both these conditions (e.g. $\int_0^\infty\frac1{(x+1)\sqrt x}\ dx=\pi$). An integral is proper if and only if it meets *neither* of these conditions: the domain of integration and the integrand are bounded.

Hence the given integrals are proper in spite of their undefined points, because finite limits (approaching on a path wholly within the domain of integration) exist at those points.

Answer (score 1):

Not only $\lim_{x\to b^+}f(x)$ should exist but also $\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)$ should sometimes. Then it is proper.